# ICEfaces ice:panelTooltip not showing

Tags: jsf, icefaces, jsf-1.2

Ok so I've been messing around with a JSF snippet supposed to render a tooltip :

```
<ice:form>
    <ice:panelGroup>
        <ice:graphicImage value="images/icon_info.gif" width="15" height="15" style="float:left;"></ice:graphicImage>
        <ice:panelToolTip>
            <f:facet name="body">
                <ice:outputText styleClass="toolTip" escape="false" value="Jeff,IfYoureSeeingThisYoureSmiling"/>
            </f:facet>
        </ice:panelToolTip>
    </ice:panelGroup>
</ice:form>
```

The problem is that when I hover the tooltip icon, no text-box is displayed. I also noticed that if I add a CommandLink to that snippet (in the panelGroup), the action will never be executed.

**My tought on the problem**

You must know that the current web page is included in another web page which already have an `<ice:form/>`. So, I think this may be caused by nested forms, no ? Note that I have no errors displayed.

I wanted to try by removing the `<ice:form>` but then I get error that it must be in a form. Note that I can't remove the form in the parent web page.

**N.B.** The JSF is written in an .xhtml file, I know this is not cool but it should work ?

**N.B.** I'm not in an `<ui:repeat/>`

**Edit  :** The bean called by the action of the commandLink is `RequestScoped` but I doubt it does matter in that case as I have other Beans used the same way that are `RequestScoped` and that works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [ICEfaces tooltip showcase](http://icefaces-ee3-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?exp=tooltip).  The `<ice:panelGroup>` has a attribute `panelTooltip` which should be assigned the id of your `<ice:panelTooltip>`.

```
<ice:form>
    <ice:panelTooltip id="myTip">
        <f:facet name="body">
            <ice:outputText styleClass="toolTip" escape="false" value="Jeff,IfYoureSeeingThisYoureSmiling"/>
        </f:facet>
    </ice:panelToolTip>

    <ice:panelGroup panelTooltip="myTip">
        <ice:graphicImage value="images/icon_info.gif" width="15" height="15" style="float:left;" />            
    </ice:panelGroup>
</ice:form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer instead of the other one because of the `<ice:form>` tag which is needed. Still, both answers are correct.

Answer (score 1):

A short research on this topic brought up, that you have to specify the tooltip ID for the text you want to add the tooltip for, similar to

```
<ice:panelGroup panelTooltip="staticTooltip" >
    <ice:outputText value="Hovering on this text will bring a panelTooltip" />
</ice:panelGroup>

<ice:panelTooltip id="staticTooltip">
    <f:facet name="body">
        <h:outputText value="This panelTooltip is static. It will be closed when the user moves the mouse out of the triggering component" />
    </f:facet>
</ice:panelTooltip>
```